# Is there a way to order animations based on components in framer motion?

Tags: reactjs, css-animations, framer-motion

Suppose I have 3 boxes rendered as a row side by side and I want to change the color of each box element to green, red and blue and I want to have this animations happen from left to right the first box should change to green and once the animation is done the second box should change to red and so on.

Is there a way to achieve this in framer motion?